# xcode UITapGestureRecognizer on scrollview not calling until second tap

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code to dismiss the keyboard if the user taps the background. It works fine if the scrollview is in the PointZero position, but if the user scrolls the view and then selects the textview, it doesn't call the "dismissKeyboard' method until the 2nd background tap.

On the first tap (for some reason) moves the scrollview offset to align with the scrollview frame to the screen bottom. The second tap will dismiss the keyboard and run the code below. I know it has to do with the scrollview. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    scrollViewRect = _scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    keyboardSize.height += 10;
    CGFloat viewBottom = CGRectGetMaxY(self.scrollView.frame);

    if ([_itemNotes isFirstResponder]) {
        CGFloat notesBottom = CGRectGetMaxY(_itemNotes.frame);
        viewBottom -= notesBottom;
        if (viewBottom < keyboardSize.height) {
            keyboardSize.height -= viewBottom;

            CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, keyboardSize.height);

            [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else {
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, scrollViewRect);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT:
So I figured out a solution but it seems like there must be a better way to handle this. The problem was because I was setting the contentOffset of the scrollView so that the contentSize was beyond the screen boundaries. Thus the first tap was moving the scrollView contentOffset back within the screen boundaries and the second was performing the tap gesture. I will post my solution below hoping that someone has a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming there must be a better solution to this but I was able to solve the issue by extending the contentSize when the keyboard is displayed and then shrinking it back down when the keyboard is hidden.

Set a float (scrollViewHeight) to hold the original content size for the reset.

```
//add this right before setting the content offset
scrollViewHeight = _scrollView.contentSize.height;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width , scrollViewHeight + keyboardSize.height);

//add this right before reseting the content offset
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width , scrollViewHeight);
```

It really seems like there must be a better way that I'm not aware of. I will have to go back through the documentation to see if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting

```
_scrollView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
_scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

This will show you exactly where your scrollview boundaries are, which may not be where you think they are, or may be covered by something else.  Also, when I open the keyboard, I generally set the scrollview frame bottom to the top of the keyboard.  Otherwise, you may have content below the keyboard you can't get to.  Not sure if this is exactly related to your issues.

Comment: In my case I am setting the textview bottom to the top of the keyboard, thanks for the tip.